# How to disable NoReverseMatch error email on production server?

Tags: python, django, http, url, exception

I about 100 emails in my inbox this morning telling me various pages don't exist (I suspect some bot was looking for security vulnerabilities). The error is:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view_profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

But when I go to the specified URL on my production server, I get my 404 page, just as I'd expect, and no email is sent. So why/how are these bots generating (what I presume is) an internal server error? And how do I prevent them?

My `view_profile` urlpattern is defined like:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$', name="view_profile")
```

Which is a sub-pattern of

```
RegexURLResolver(r'^contacts/', 'profiles.views.user_profile'),
```

It's defined exactly like any of my other URL patterns, and it requires an ID to be passed to it....so I don't know how it's being hit with no arguments.

The full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response
   response = callback(request, **param_dict)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/views/defaults.py", line 19, in page_not_found
   return http.HttpResponseNotFound(t.render(RequestContext(request, {'request_path': request.path})))

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
   return self._render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
   return self.nodelist.render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
   return compiled_parent._render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
   return self.nodelist.render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 311, in render
   return self.nodelist_true.render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/home/me/my/website/lib/python2.7/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 450, in render
   raise e

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view_profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.


<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'csrftoken': '89867bc39db49a791bb24dce06e26b6f',
 'sessionid': 'd0db456ae01005678d1538b00ae26dd1'},
META:{'CSRF_COOKIE': '89867bc39db49a791bb24dce06e26b6f',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=89867bc39db49a791bb24dce06e26b6f; sessionid=d0db456ae01005678d1538b00ae26dd1',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'myproject.net',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; GTB6; Zango 10.3.75.0)',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '39.47.147.220',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': 'myproject.net',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER': 'myproject.net',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/web/',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/me/my/website/myproject.wsgi/web/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '40577',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/web/',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/home/me/my/website/myproject.wsgi',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'SERVER_ADMIN': '[no address given]',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'myproject.net',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1',
 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'my.server.com|',
 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '54084',
 'mod_wsgi.process_group': '',
 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 3),
 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0xae05ef8>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0xb18c1d0>,
 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0xae05e58>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 1)}>
```

Paths renamed to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere (presumably in templates), you resolve view_profile with empty string instead of id.  So find out why is it happening and fix it

Comment: I just ran a search on `view_profile`. All the `{% urls %}` have an ID. Also, they're all locked behind `@login_required` anyway, so they shouldn't be accessible. And like I said, if I visit the URL given, I get the 404 page........oh...but that uses the standard template.....which has a user specific thing in there... `user.pk` is probably null.

Comment: yep here you go. Also there's helpful option in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-string-if-invalid for debugging this kind of bugs, you set it to 'EMPTY' and quickly find out what happened because url exception will have EMPTY as arg

Comment: @DmitrySchvchenko: Oh nice! didn't know about that settings. Thanks! Perhap's I'll make it "EMPTY" in debug-mode only...that'd be nice. Actually, this particular error never happens in debug because you don't get the standard 404. Probably why I never noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the bot is simply requesting all mappable urls (as a site crawler would) and not respecting redirect requests or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a robots.txt file to ward off bots. Add this to your main urls.py file. DISALLOW_ROBOTS should be set as True in settings.py for the development environment.

```
if settings.DISALLOW_ROBOTS:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /", mimetype="text/plain")),
    )
else:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow: ", mimetype="text/plain")),
    )
```

Comment: I've got a robots.txt. Did I mention this was most likely a hacking attempt? i.e., I don't think they exactly respect robots.txt.